# Puppet validate lookup of ip address with port eg 1.2.3.4:5678

Tags: validation, variables, puppet

I am performing a lookup as a top scope variable in a Puppet manifest for values that will contain a concatenated IP address and port, e.g., 1.2.3.4:5678.

I know that I can do validation on either IP address OR port with the following:

`Stdlib::IP::Address::V4  $server = lookup(profiles::something::server)`

or

`Stdlib::Port $server = lookup(profiles::something::server)`

however, I want to validate both together, for example

`String[[Stdlib::IP::Address::V4]:[Stdlib::Port]] $server = lookup(profiles::something::server)`

However, I cannot find a way other than splitting them in the manifest and performing in-line validation.

Is there a way to do a combined lookup validation of a top-scope variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you show for validating the form of the value relies on data type aliases defined in the puppetlabs-stdlib module.  If there is no suitable alias there for what you want then you can always write a full [type expression](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.19/lang_data_type.html) for what you want.  In that event, I would recommend also defining a [type alias](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.19/lang_type_aliases.html) for that in some module under your control, as a suitable alias name is much easier to comprehend than a complex type expression.  You could look at the type aliases defined in stdlib to help get yourself going.

Comment: Thanks John, you are correct about restriction to what is in Stdlib.  I was trying to stitch 2 checks together such as below but I don't think it will work.

" String[[Stdlib::IP::Address::V4]:[Stdlib::Port]]  "

Comment: No, you cannot compose types that way.  I already linked you to the docs for what you *can* do.  You probably want to write your own type alias from scratch, *inspired by* stdlib's.  In particular, here is one of the alternatives for `Stdlib::IP::Address::V4`: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/main/types/ip/address/v4/nosubnet.pp.  This particular one is regex-based, and that would be my recommendation for yours, too.  You could even take that, rename it, and add the needed bits for the port part.